# laravel collection : How to combine two different type array and asign key and new item

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have 2 array like this

```
$packers_id = [
[984538,{"PartCode":"packs701620010","Qty":"13","ID":"1398163","Date":"2020\/08\/08 15:4:6"}],
[984538,{"PartCode":"packs701620020","Qty":"1","ID":"1398164","Date":"2020\/08\/08 15:4:6"}],
[984543,{"PartCode":"packs701620010","Qty":"13","ID":"1398163","Date":"2020\/08\/08 15:4:6"}],
[984543,{"PartCode":"packs701620020","Qty":"1","ID":"1398164","Date":"2020\/08\/08 15:4:6"}]
]
```

how to change the array using laravel collection method to be like this and add some item

```
$packers_id = [
{"Arr_ID":"984538","PartCode":"packs701620010","Qty":"13","ID":"1398163","Date":"2020\/08\/08 15:4:6","changeby":"me"},
{"Arr_ID":"984538","PartCode":"packs701620020","Qty":"1","ID":"1398164","Date":"2020\/08\/08 15:4:6","changeby":"me"},
{"Arr_ID":"984543","PartCode":"packs701620010","Qty":"13","ID":"1398163","Date":"2020\/08\/08 15:4:6","changeby":"me"},
{"Arr_ID":"984543","PartCode":"packs701620020","Qty":"1","ID":"1398164","Date":"2020\/08\/08 15:4:6","changeby":"me"}
]
```

I can do it using foreach but I dont want it because I saw there is map method and other method in laravel collection method.
My target is to get clean code and fastest timing.

Comment: You don't need laravel to change multi dimensional array to one dimensional..! Just use the plain `foreach` to change

Comment: I see comment about laravel method, which is faster. correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Laravel is not a language but rather a framework so it does uses either `forEach, array_walk` or something similar helpers internally that `PHP` provides

Comment: You have two ID fields in result array!

Comment: However you can do like this
$array2= collect($array1)
->map(function($data){
  $data[1]['ID']=$data[0];
return $data[0];
});

Comment: Sorry itis Arr_ID, i put wrong example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe we can use the `mapToGroup` function based on the laravel documentation.

```
$collection = collect([
[984538,{"PartCode":"packs701620010","Qty":"13","ID":"1398163","Date":"2020\/08\/08 15:4:6"}],
[984538,{"PartCode":"packs701620020","Qty":"1","ID":"1398164","Date":"2020\/08\/08 15:4:6"}],
[984543,{"PartCode":"packs701620010","Qty":"13","ID":"1398163","Date":"2020\/08\/08 15:4:6"}],
[984543,{"PartCode":"packs701620020","Qty":"1","ID":"1398164","Date":"2020\/08\/08 15:4:6"}]
]);
```

then we can mapToGroups our newly made collection.

```
    $grouped = $collection->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
        return [
           $item[0] => $item['ID'],
           $item[1]["PartCode"] => $item["PartCode"],
           $item[1]["Qty"] => $item["Qty"],
           ....
        ];
    });
```

be careful of the duplicate ID that can lead to new errors though.

Comment: No sorry, i got wrong example, actually itis not duplicate ID, but become "Arr_ID"